# Calendar design

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, calendar

I found a design for calendar which is below.

[image]

Previously i was using ajax calendar extendar, but suddenly my client needs this in his application.

I have tried styling for ID,class but none of them worked..

as you can see in this image, there is "Clear Dates"..How to put this text and handle that..

[This calendar url](https://www.airbnb.com.sg/)

It is similar to jquery ui i think, but i m not sure..

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a jquery UI DatePicker.

And If you want do the '**clear date**' button, U can use this code.

```
$(function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true,
      beforeShow: function( input ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          var clearBut = $( input )
            .datepicker( "widget" )
            .find( ".ui-datepicker-buttonpane" );

          $( "<button>", {
            text: "Clear date",
            click: function() {
              $.datepicker._clearDate( input );
            }
          }).appendTo( clearBut );
        }, 3 );
      }
    });
 });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pkZYV/)

Comment: if we are adding showbuttonpanel:true, other than "clear dates" two more buttons are there..I dont want that..I need similar to the above image..